# Not getting ajax response in TYPO3

Tags: ajax, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am using this in my `setup.txt` to generate ajax calls

```
myAjaxPage  = PAGE
myAjaxPage  {
 config {
   disableAllHeaderCode = 1
   debug = 0
   no_cache = 1
   additionalHeaders {
     10 {
       header = Content-Type: application/json
       replace = 1
     }
   }
 }
 typeNum = 427590
 10 < tt_content.list.20.documentcenter_list
}
```

but I am not able to get any response from my controller whereas the Network status gives me 200 as seen in this [header](http://prntscr.com/k8sy14) and [response](http://prntscr.com/k8t1ks)

What am I doing wrong, or if anyone can guide me would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are using a page which contains a `typeNum` parameter you have to add it to your `URL`.

```
http://exmample.com/index.php?id=48&type=427590
```

This is the format how your URL should look like.

Comment: How do I know which action to call? I am still getting a blank response

Comment: `type=427590` determine your actions and ajax behavior this will be in your Typoscript.

Answer (score 0):

you need a setup like this:

```
tx_cardealer_ajax = PAGE
tx_cardealer_ajax {
    features {
        skipDefaultArguments = 1
    }

    typeNum = 4711
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/plain
        no_cache = 1
    }

    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = Cardealer
        pluginName = Cardealer
        vendorName = EXOTEC
        controller = Cardealer
        switchableControllerActions {
            Cardealer {
                1 = ajax
                2 = list
                3 = filter
                4 = show
                10 < tt_content.list.20.contentautocomplete_content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it still is not working. I am getting a blank response page

Comment: can i see your setup?